# How to archive a new target in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I created a new target in my Xcode project with the intention of using it to build a "beta" version of my application instead of using a single target and swapping environment variables and other things constantly when I do my builds.

The new target is a different version and build number than my original target, and it uses a different bundle identifier. I am trying to archive the new target and upload the .ipa file to my device management software to distribute the app to my users, but when I upload the .ipa file, it appears to be an archive of the first target because it lists the first target's bundle Id, version and build numbers instead. Are targets allowed to be used this way? I have the beta target selected when I click archive but I'm not sure what else I could be doing wrong.

Also let me know if there is any additional information or screenshots I can provide and I would be happy to do so.

Comment: Can you build-and-run the second app target? In other words, is this just an archiving issue?

Comment: I can build and run the second app target. I archive the app with the second target selected, but then when it completes, in the Window Organizer screen that shows the list of archives, the details still shows the first targets bundle Id

Comment: Could it be that you're looking in the wrong list? The archives are listed app (on the left side); these are two different apps. It sounds like you might be looking in the first app even though you archived the second app.

Comment: I don't think so, the timestamp for it lines up with when I archived it and it has the correct name. The bundle Id and version and build numbers just don't match up for what theyre listed on the target

Comment: But I'm saying, never mind the timestamp; it is in a whole separate category (i.e. the iOS apps listed on the left of the Organizer)? If not, you're not archiving a different app. For example, suppose you accidentally created a framework or extension target and not an app target. You could still archive starting from the framework or extension, but you'd be archiving the first app, because the framework is part of the first app, not a separate app.

Comment: Right, it lumped it together with all the other archives I've done. So I must be doing something wrong because its not using that target when it archives

Comment: Right, so you're not actually building a different app target. I'm suggesting your second target might not be an app target. See my screen shot below.

Comment: To create the target I just duplicated the first target so it should be but ill take a deeper look

Comment: "To create the target I just duplicated the first target" That could be your mistake. Don't do that! Create a new target and choose one of the app templates from the dialog (they are in the third group). That way, you get correct settings all the way down. What you did clearly leaves some old settings in place, and you don't know what they are.

Comment: Good thought, let me try that and I will get back to you

Answer (score 2):

Two app targets is a perfectly good way to generate two apps from one codebase. When I do that, I can't reproduce any issue.

Make sure your second target *is* an app target. When you archive, you should end up with two completely different archive folders, as shown in the iOS Apps listing on the left side of the Organizer window:

[image]

When creating your new app target, make a *new* app target, using the New Target dialog:

[image]

That way, you get a consistent, self-contained target that is a *different app*. Do not merely duplicate the existing app target, because you don't know what needs changing to make it a different app.